# In macOS, How to get back the contents of `.zshrc` file after installing `Oh-My-Zsh` framework which replaced it with its configurations?

Tags: macos, oh-my-zsh, zshrc

After installing **Oh My Zsh** framework on my macOS to manage my Zsh configurations, I found that the original contents of the `.zshrc` file have been completely replaced with the Oh-My-Zsh configurations. There were many aliases and environment variables in the old file that I was using.

Is there a way to get those old configurations back to work with the new Oh-My-Zsh configurations?

Comment: Stack Overflow is only for questions explicitly about the practice of software development and tools exclusively for that use. Tools useful to developers and non-developers alike are a better topic for [unix.se].

Answer (score 10):

When installing [Oh-My-Zsh](https://ohmyz.sh/) framework, it moves all contents of the existing `.zshrc` file into a file it creates called `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh`.

To get the contents of the `.zshrc` file back, open both files in the editor you prefer and copy your old configurations from `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` file and place it in `~/.zshrc` file.

To run any command, open a new terminal window so the changes take effect.

If you are using VSCode, you can use it to open both files like this:

```
code ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh

code ~/.zshrc
```

Answer (score 6):

simple command to add contents from your previous .zshrc file

```
cat ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh >> ~/.zshrc && source ~/.zshrc
```